# MacBook Air won't power on

Tags: macbook-pro, power, startup

My MacBook Air won't turn on. I plugged in the charger and it says it's charging. When I turn it on, the light instantly turns green for a few seconds, and then it goes to amber.

What's going on?

I also had an error before, when it was alive: the dreaded frozen bluetooth keyboard assistant error. I didn't make that one go away but I'm not sure if it relates to this issue.

Comment: Try SMC and NVRAM resets. If those don’t help, try booting into recovery mode and reinstalling the OS. If you can’t boot to recovery mode, try booting to internet recovery mode and reinstall the OS. If you can’t do any of these things, let us know.

Comment: It's unlikely an [SMC reset](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295) will fix the issue, but give it a shot for good measure.  The symptoms you're describing point to a logic board failure....it's time to take it in for service.

Answer (score 1):

Try resetting the NVRAM and the SMC on your Mac then see if it can come on or if you detect any noises or lights detailing some form of life.

**NVRAM aka PRAM**
https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063

> How to reset NVRAM
>
> Shut down your Mac, then turn it on and immediately press and hold
>   these four keys together: Option, Command, P, and R. You can release
>   the keys after about 20 seconds, during which your Mac might appear to
>   restart.
>
> On Mac computers that play a startup sound, you can release the keys
>   after the second startup sound. On iMac Pro, you can release the keys
>   after the Apple logo appears and disappears for the second time.

**SMC (System Management Controller)** 
https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295

> How to reset the SMC on Mac notebooks
>
> First, determine whether the battery is removable. Most older Mac
>   notebooks have removable batteries. Mac notebooks that have
>   nonremovable batteries include MacBook Pro (Early 2009 and later), all
>   models of MacBook Air, MacBook (Late 2009), and MacBook (Retina,
>   12-inch, Early 2015 and later). Learn more about Mac notebook
>   batteries.
>
> If the battery is nonremovable:
>
> 1. Choose Apple menu > Shut Down.
> 2. After your Mac shuts down, press Shift-Control-Option on the left side of the built-in keyboard, then press the power button at the same
>      time. Hold these keys and the power button for 10 seconds. If you have
>      a MacBook Pro with Touch ID, the Touch ID button is also the power
>      button.
> 3. Release all keys.
> 4. Press the power button again to turn on your Mac.
>
> If the battery is removable:
>
> 1. Shut down your Mac.
> 2. Remove the battery. If you need help removing the battery, contact
>      an Apple Authorized Service Provider or Apple Retail Store.
> 3. Press and hold the power button for 5 seconds.
> 4. Reinstall the battery.
> 5. Press the power button again to turn on your Mac.

Comment: It didn't work, unfortunately.

Comment: Then you'll need to take it into an Apple Store to determine if it's either a battery issue or a logic board problem.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the JTAG connector, this happened on my MacBook Pro and removing it fixed it.

**NOTE:** The JTAG connector is the unused connector on the motherboard. Double check it first before removing it.